# Changing file extension for 7000 files in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have thousands of files sitting in a MYSQLi database with extension ***.BLAH*** . I need to change the extension for all those files to ***.BLAH2*** .

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: @usr1234567 haven't tried anything yet. This is on a live site so I need to be 100% certain the method will work before I run it.

Comment: You need a test system, maybe with a copy of your data. There you can try and play around. Stackoverflow is not meant to compensate your lack of knowledge and your lack of a test system.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a simple update set and replace.

```
UPDATE files set file = replace(file, 'blah', 'blah2')
```

Comment: `replace(file, '.blah', '.blah2')` will more secure

Comment: I will also add where condition - file like '%.blah' . It is possible that file name for example will be 'file.blah.name.blah'. You may be nitpicking, but the author did not exclude such a case

Comment: Many thanks for responses guys. Just interested to double check the code before I run a test. ..  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE files set file = replace(file, '.blah', '.blah2')"); .. seems so simple. Gotta love coding.